# handling duplicates that has varying values in another column of a data frame

Tags: r, duplicates, match

I have a large data frame whose columns have tried to simplify as follows for clarity purposes.

```
 refined.data  value            rawdata
        ab         4               wd
        cd         8               ab
        ef         9y              cd
        ab         5p              gh
        gh         7               tg
        cd         6k              hg
        ef         3q              ef
        tg         9w              pw
        wq         10              dz
```

a column of `refined.data` has elements of which some of them are duplicated within the same column but with a unique value in the column of `Value`.
i wish to  produce a new data frame with two columns whereby  `rawdata` column has been matched with the column of  `refined.data`. The matches should be linked with their corresponding column `values`(unique) as shown below.desired results

```
NewDataFrame=

matches         value
ab                4
ab                5p
cd                8
cd                6k
ef                9y
ef                3q
tg                9w
wq                10
```

so how am i supposed to loop in the two columns such that if it encounters a first match it should append a corresponding value in the column `value`, second match should also append its corresponding value till all the matches of a single element are exhausted.
eg. the

```
           matches   value
1st match of `ab`     4
2nd match of `ab`     5p
```

in other words duplicates in the column `matches` should be maintained but `Values` should be unique

any suggestion is invited and will be appreciated.am literally stack.cant do a thing without first fixing this "mess".am green in R

Comment: I don't understand. `NewDataFrame` seems to contain the same data as the original data frame, except that the first column name has been changed from "refined.data" to "matches" and the rows have been re-ordered... So is your question actually about re-ordering the rows of the data frame?

Comment: @konvas "NewDataFrame" is my desired result.Thats how i want my final data frame to look like."matches" is a column that contain a match of "refined.data" and "rawdata".Notice that in "NewDataFrame" each match(refined.data & rawdata),regardless of the duplicates, has a unique value to it.So, my question is about maintaining duplicates of each match rather than re-ordering of the rows.kindly help me out if you are conversant with this kind of problem

Comment: Sorry but what you want to do is still not clear to me. Could you explain what you mean by "matching" rawdata to refined.data?

Comment: Why is `gh` not in `NewDataFrame?`

Comment: @MarkMiller i just manually took a sample of the ones that match in order to explain the programming crisis am in.so there is a possibility that some matches are missing out of th 'NewDataFrame'

Comment: @konvas what i want in simple terms is that rawdata should be matched against refined.data. evidently, most of the elements in rawdata are matching in refined.data in more than once, so i want in each row of single match to have a column of value. for example "ab" in rowdata appears twice in refined.data and each occurrence has a unique value , so i wanna have a newdataframe with two columns whereby all "ab" are appearing in the same column-"Matches" as well as their respective Values in the other column as shown           ab=4,                                                           ab=5p

Comment: @Smock Do you mean you want to keep the elements in refined.data that exist in rawdata as well? If that's the case, then why is wq in your desired output, since wq is not in rawdata?

Comment: @konvas yeah i want to keep all elements in refined.data that exist in rawdata,sorry for that typo.its supposed to be wd not wq.

Comment: @Smock But wd appears in rawdata but not in refined data... So why is it kept if we are keeping only elements of refined.data that are in rawdata? I think the R code for this will be extremely simple, the problem here is not the code but formulating properly what you are trying to achieve. On what basis is wd to be kept? And why does it have an associated value of 10?

Comment: @konvas let me clarify that its not a must that each element in rawdata should appear in refined.data but at least there are some that exist in both and That is why the aspect of 'match' between the data-sets comes in so that in each match found,regardless of duplicates, should be assigned a 'value' associated to it. That is where my knowledge in programming stops.i cant figure out how to maintain the duplicates(obtained from matching) while assigning to each of them a unique 'Value'

Comment: @Smock Sorry but I will insist that the main challenge here is not writing the code, but stating clearly what you want to do. We need to clarify two things: (1) How is the column "matches" constructed (2) After "matches" has been constructed, what value is assigned to each element of matches. Let's start with (1). If an element appears 2 times in refined.data and at least once in rawdata, then it has to appear 2 times in "matches" (eg ab). Elements in refined.data that are not in rawdata are excluded (as wq shows). And elements that are in rawdata but not in refined.data? What happens to them?

Comment: @konvas (1)column **matches** is constructed by matching the two columns(refined.data and rawdata) using either %in% or match functions in R.(2)after matches has been found they have to to be assigned their associated Values found in the column _values_ (3) if there happens to be more than ones in the matches like case of 'ab' , then each of 'ab' should have its own value eg ab=4 for the first match and ab=5p for the second match.(4) about elements that are found in refined but not in rawdata should be disregarded..of interest are the ones in the column **matches**